# .Net Core Test Project keeps on losing System references

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a simple .net core MVC Webservice. When I run it it works fine.

I added in a test project and a couple of tests, and everything worked ok.

This morning I refactored my webservice so that the dao code I was using was moved to a seperate assembly. As soon as I did this I started to get http500 errors, and my test project would no longer run.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

A quick google didn't turn anything up, so I deleted references to my dao assembly project and copied all my code back to the original project. Now the original project works, but I am still getting binding errors in my test project. Fusion shows the error;

```
Test method TestService_Tests.ControllerTests.TestGetEnquiries threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe

A detailed error log follows. 

Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/users/matt/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/TestService/TestService_Tests/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : ReportingService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

I assume that in adding a .net core assembly in that I have caused a configuration issue somewhere. But how do I track it down, short of deleting the test project, starting again and hoping that the configuration problem is in the test project?

By trial and error I can say that the error happens at the line it invokes the controller. 
Dummy tests that do not test the controller work. But the issue arises as soon as a test is done on any of my code.

```
{
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"ReportingBusinessLayer": "1.0.0-*",
"System.Runtime": "4.1.0" },

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
},

"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "Areas/**/Views",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
},

"scripts": {
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder  publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your project.json file?

Comment: I am trying to use xUnit now, if I can't resolve that I will restore and do that.

Comment: Project.json file added

Comment: Using NuGet and the offline Store I can find that the required runtime (and version) is installed, which makes it more confusing. But the System.runtime assemblies are not in the test librarys bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Check your copy local settings. Frequently when references fail to resolve after refactoring it's due to copy local being false somewhere or the references not being added to both the provider and consumer projects. I don't imagine this would be necessary for this system library, but it's worth checking since I don't know what other frameworks you have in place.

Also make sure your provider library is not targeting a different assembly or .NET runtime version than your consumer.

Comment: Copy local and references are there. I have gone through a whole load of different .net versions, but no joy either.
I've doe this loads of times before without issue. This time I am using .net core, which is the only real difference to my previous projects.

Comment: Try using a [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the calling assembly. Do you have the core references in both of the projects or just the DAO project? If just the DAO, you'll want it in both.

Comment: According to nuget it is in both. Fusion isn't finding any errors that I can see. And the code compiles and runs fine, its just the testing. I might give up and try somethign like xunit in a minute, see if that makes the problem disappear.

Comment: It is just the testing? Add your dependencies to your test assembly as well, then. I didn't realize you could run it but not within the test harness. Sounds like your test assembly which I acting as the caller is missing a reference or on a different version.

Comment: I understand that, but when I physically added the reference in via browse, it said it was already there. It had to be something to do with the TestProject, probably somethign I needed to add in the json file. (Which is what I am not battling with with xUnit)

Comment: Project.json file added. xUnit was even worse for dependencies, so I decided I ought to get this one solved if I can before I learn a new framework